# How to print names of all the tables in the database in MySql2 in Ruby?

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, green-shoes

I want to create buttons (using Shoes) of all the tables in my database.

I am a beginner and this is my first GUI project 'Stock Management', I am using shoes library in Ruby and want to store and manage the data in MySql2 with Ruby. I typed some code but its not working

**path/main.rb**

```
require 'mysql2'
require 'green_shoes'

client = Mysql2::Client.new (host: "localhost",username: "root", password: "xyz", database: "Ruby")

Shoes.app do
    components = client.query("SHOW TABLES")
    components.each do |item|
        button item
    end
end`
```

Gives nothing.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: sir, sorry if i messed up things, i am asking here for 1st time and I write the 'urgent' because i have to submit the project to my workplace in one or two days and still the project is in Blueprint only.

Comment: Sure, I understand that it is urgent for you. But the point of that link - which I have had to post hundreds of times on this site - is that when you are addressing **volunteers**, your urgency is irrelevant. In fact, the more you mention it, the less likely it is that you will get help, since it reflects a belief that your questions are more important than the other questions here. It is worth understanding that **this is not advice specific to Stack Overflow** - this applies anywhere on and off the internet.

Comment: Sure Sir, I will not post such words next time! I understand what you want to say

Answer (score 0):

You could query them from the `information_schema`:

```
components = client.query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables")
```

Comment: gives irrelevant output see it on this link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZI65TD0TWK9zjeXqDsDaV035XpNCSPom

Comment: Upload a screenshot to imgur and edit your question to add a link. Someone (e.g., me) will edit it to inline the image.

Comment: i attached the screenshot link of my googledrive please check it

Comment: when i type, components = client.query("SELECT table_name FROM Ruby.tables") - it gives compilation error but works when i type, components = client.query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables")